# NLog LogEventInfo to log exception

Tags: exception, nlog, nlog-configuration

I am using the LogEventInfo to log both to a log file and database entry. I also want to log the stacktrace when exception is thrown to the log file. I thought I just need to set the Exception property in the LogEventInfo to the exception I want to log, but it didn't work, The log file only contains "Error my message". Where did I do wrong? Thanks.

The NLog.config is like

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="localLogFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="localLogFile" />
```

And the C# code

```
LogEventInfo logentity = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "", "my message");
logentity.Properties["errormsg"] = msg;

logentity.Exception = new Exception("Dummy");

logger.Error(logentity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also to print the exception in the layout, using `${exception}`.

So a good layout would be:

```
layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception}" />
```

Check the [docs for `${exception}`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer) for various render options.